# How to create equivalent of Java's CardLayout or ASP:MultiView with UIView and subViews?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Ideally I'd like to be able to create the views in Interface Builder and then swap them with code.

Any pointers to sample code or tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the pairing of UIViewController and UIView lets you do.  You can lay out the UIView for a UIViewController in Interface Builder, and then just use them from your code with ease.